# Can I do content based polling in Biztalk server using WSS Adapter

Tags: c#, dynamic, biztalk, wss

I have scenario where  I have to poll documents from sharepoint library based on some conditions.
e.g. fetch documents which has `status==Readytoprocess` and then based upon unique number present in document fetch its content file from another sharepoint library.

What is the best approach doing in biztalk? Is there any way where I can create Dynamic Receive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create a view in Sharepoint, with a
   status==Readytoprocess-filter, and let BizTalk poll from there.

   1. Make a request to the Sharepoint service for the content file.

Regards
Martin